# How I implement the GetEnumerator method in my generic List?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating my own Generic List data structure for my to better understand it in general. I want my List to be able to use the foreach method. I am not sure how one goes about implementing the IEnumerable Interface. Here Is My code so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace DataStructures
{
    public class List<T>: IList<T>, IEnumerable where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        private const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 8;
        private T[] listArray;
        private int arrayElementCounter = 0;

        public List()
        {
            listArray = new T[DEFAULT_SIZE];
        }

        public int Count{get{return this.arrayElementCounter;}}

        public void Add(T element)
        {
            growIfArrayIsFull();
            this.listArray[arrayElementCounter] = element;
            this.arrayElementCounter++;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            listArray = new T[DEFAULT_SIZE];
        }

        public bool Contains(T element)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= arrayElementCounter; i++)
            {
                if (this.listArray.Equals(element))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void growIfArrayIsFull()
        {
            T[] newListArray;
            if (this.arrayElementCounter == this.listArray.Length)
            {
                newListArray = new T[this.listArray.Length * 2];
                Array.Copy(listArray, newListArray, arrayElementCounter);
                listArray = newListArray;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return listArray.GetEnumerator();
        }

    // Ignore this First
    // private int CompareTo(T otherElement)
    // {
    //            
    // }
    }
}
```

I Populated my list with 5 integers as follows

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);

foreach (var i in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

However when what prints to my console is as follows

> 1
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0

its showing every element in the inner array. Can someone help me remedy this?

Comment: You'll have to keep in mind the amount of items in the list (not just allocated): https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140

Comment: Your code should involve `arrayElementCounter` and that means you can't lean on `listArray.GetEnumerator()`, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Side note: `List<>` is not a wise name for your own class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman what would you suggest i Change it to? ArrayList? Ive only been learning how to progrom for a few months. You have to forgive the quality of my code.

Comment: ArrayList is also an existing library class, albeit less frequently used now. I spot a `T: IComparable<T>` so maybe `SortableList<>` or just stick to `MyList<>`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Anyway's the purpose of doing this is just practice in how  to make classes in general. Trying to incorporate everything I know so far about OOP: inheritance, abstraction, encapsulation. On a side note, where can i post this code for people to review?

Comment: You could put it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/